# Extract array of bytes from GVariant

Tags: gtk3

I want to pass an array of bytes such as `[1,2,3,4,5]` between processes using DBus. I understand, that I can use the [BYTE type](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#basic-types) to declare an array of bytes (i.e., `ay`) and then use `GVariant` to store and retrieve the values? How can I create a `GVariant` that can hold this data and how can I get it back out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GVariant` can be created using `g_variant_new_from_data`. The first two arguments are the type of the variant (`ay`) as well as a pointer to an array of bytes with the inputs for the variant.

```c
guint8 input[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

GVariant * variant;

variant = g_variant_new_from_data(G_VARIANT_TYPE ("ay"),
                                  input,
                                  G_N_ELEMENTS(input),
                                  TRUE,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL);
```

To get the data back out we can use `g_variant_get_fixed_array`.

```c
guint8 * array = NULL;

gsize n_elements;

array = g_variant_get_fixed_array (variant,
                                   &n_elements,
                                   sizeof(guint8));

g_assert (n_elements == 5);
g_assert (array != NULL);
```